# Is there any easier proof for derivative of $x^e$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to prove that $\frac{d}{dx}x^e=ex^{e-1}$.

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}x^e=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{(x+h)^e-x^e}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}x^e \cdot \dfrac {e^{e  \ln \left({1 + \frac h x} \right)} - 1} {e  \ln {\left(1 + \dfrac h x\right)} } \cdot \dfrac {e  \ln {\left(1 + \dfrac h x\right)}} {\dfrac h x} \cdot \dfrac 1 x = e x^{e - 1}$ since

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \mathop \to 0} \frac {e^ x - 1} x = 1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \mathop \to 0} \frac { \ln {(1 + x)} } x = 1$.

Is there any way which is simpler?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If you want to be careful, you need some argument for why both of those limits exist (the two which equal $1$). Also, this proof doesn't work for $x=0$.

Comment: I don't know how much simpler you could want it than a 3 line proof

Comment: There is something off here. You seem to want to establish a rule of differentiation but what does $x^e$ even mean to you? Does it mean $x^e := e^{e\ln x}$? If so, then you find the derivative of $x \mapsto x^e$ using its _definition_ (and the chain rule).

Answer (score 1):

$(x+h)^e$ can be expanded using the Binomial theorem to get
$$
(x+h)^e = x^e + \binom{e}{1}x^{e-1} h + h^2 (\cdot)
$$
and now $\binom{e}{1} = e$, the term $x^e$ is subtracted and cancels and everything to the right gets multiplied by a nonzero power of $h$ and cancels in the limit as well.

You do need an extended definition of the Binomial Coefficient $\binom{r}{k}$ for real $r$, which is commonly in use in combinatorics...

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple application of the power rule, i.e. $$\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$$
However, if the question assumes that one doesn't know the power rule, then the limit definition is the only other way to prove it.